# SQL: Ambiguity on key fields

Tags: sql, relational-database

I don't understand why the interpreter cannot handle the following:

```
SELECT id
FROM a
  INNER JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
```

This query wil result in an error: `Ambiguous column name 'id'`

Which makes sense because the column in defined in multiple tables in my query. However, I clearly stated to only return the rows where the id's of both table are the same. So it wouldn't matter what table the id is from.

So just out of curiosity: Is there a reason why the interpreter demands a table for the field?

*(My example is from SQLServer, not sure if other interpreters CAN handle this?)*

Comment: well if the interpreter could make that decision - ***HOW*** should it pick which column to use? Should it use `a.id` and why? Or should it use `b.id` - and why???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's be clear about a few things.  First, it is always a good idea to include table aliases when referring to columns.  This makes the SQL easier to understand.

Second, you are assuming that because of the `=` in the `on` condition, the two fields are the *same*.  This is not true.  The *values* are the same.

For instance, one field could be `int` and the other `float` (I do not recommend using `float` for join keys, but it is allowed).  What is the type of `id`?  SQL wants to assign a type to all columns, and it is not clear what type to assign.

More common examples abound.  One `id` might be a primary key and defined `NOT NULL`.  The other might be a foreign keys and quite nullable.  What is the nullability of just `id`?

In other words, SQL is doing the right thing.  This is not about whether SQL can recognize something obvious, which sometimes it does.  This is about a column being genuinely ambiguous and the SQL compiler not knowing how to define the result in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! There is more to a JOIN than I first thought of.

Answer (score 1):

How do you exepect the interpreter to know which column to use ?

Since it doesn't have a real brain (sadly..!), you need to explicitly specify the table where you want the id from.

In this example it could be :

```
SELECT a.id
FROM a
   INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id
```

Even if the id values are the same, the column still has to come from one of the tables which the interpreter cannot choose for you ;-)

Comment: But is there a limitation WHY the interpreter cannot make that decision?

Comment: The limitation is the fact that the engine has to take the information from one of the tables, and even if the values are the same, the DBMS is not made to pick a choice for us.

Comment: @Hazaart: well if the interpreter could make that decision - ***HOW*** should it pick which column to use? Should it use `a.id` and why? Or should it use `b.id` - and why???

Comment: It could for example choose 'a' because its the first table in the SELECT containing that field. But as Gordon pointed out, the two columns are not necessarely the same. So the decision cannot be made by the interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT id, should be SELECT a.id since id is in both tables it does not know "which one" you referring to.